# Text following the center of a page

Tags: text, center

i'm trying to make a simple header (HTML) with some text ( one word ). I would like the text to follow the center of the page, i mean that when i shrink the page width with the mouse i want the text change its position to the new center of the page.
Please help, thanks

Comment: You have to tell exactly what you are trying to do. is "onw word" a typo, and you are trying to do something in MS-Word? Or is this HTML?

Comment: On yes, sorry, it's a html page.

Comment: do you have a sample html? it is probably some percentage CSS tweak

Comment: No, I just started it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the sample code. The important thing is the CSS "text-align". Does this help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
   <title></title>
   <meta name="description" content="">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>

    <style type="text/css">
       p.centerPara{text-align: center}
    </style>

    <p class="centerPara">Hello world!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code. It might be a little simpler. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title goes here</title>
<style type="text/css">

#banner{
width:100%
/*Additional banner code */
}

#banner h1{
text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="banner">
<h1>OneWord</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Basically, the same thing. Text-align:center is the most important thing.